# Equal-height side-by-side floating elements

Tags: css, height, css-float

Sorry for a very simple question, but I'm just beginning with HTML & CSS and I want to create a `<div>` and two `<div>`s inside of it (one floating on the left side and one on the right). I want them both to have equal height (inherit it from the parent, so `height: 100%`), but something does not work like expected.

Here's some text below the red div (especially in smaller resolutions):
http://jsfiddle.net/KqbtG/

This solution is almost perfect and looks exactly like expected but the red div is above the blue one (Lorem ipsum do etc. is inivsible):

http://jsfiddle.net/4EnF9/1/

Any ideas? I can't have fixed height, because I'll have pleny of these divs and different content in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
}

#menu {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;  
}

#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

You have to do two things:

1. Set the height of the container div so it can be inherited
2. make sure content has height :100%

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, with the red div going overtop of the blue div, its' because the red div is positioned absolute, which effectively removes it from the "flow" of the page.

To fix this, add a `margin-left:100px` to the right (blue) div to move it out from underneath the red div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4EnF9/2/